# Python: Codeacademy: Classes

Tags: python, class

### I am learning about classes with CodeAcademy (Python).

Here are the instructions:

01.Outside your class definition, create a variable called zebra and set it equal to calling Animal(). Inside the parentheses, pass in the string "Jeffrey".
02.print out your zebra's name.

---

Here is my code:

```
class Animal(object):

def __init__(self, name ):
    self.name = name 

zebra = Animal("Jeffrey")

print zebra.name
```

---

Code Academy returns:

" Oops, try again. Did you declare a variable called zebra?"

---

I am confused as to why I am getting this error. I believe I have followed the very simple instructions and the code does what it asks: prints out the zebra's name. Any ideas as to why I am receiving this error? Any help will be greatly appreciated during this learning process!

Thank you advance.

Comment: I see an indentation error in the `__init__` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, unlike most other languages, [indentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) matters.  You do not need to be exactly 8 spaces indented, or what have you, but you need some form of consistent indentation for classes, methods, loops, ifs, etc. Change your code to:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name ):
        self.name = name 

zebra = Animal("Jeffrey")

print zebra.name
```